# Comparing 2 dto List and set the values using Java streams

Tags: arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I am stuck on making comparisons between 2 Dto Lists and setting their values.

```
      List<DbDTO> dbList = data
      List<PriDTO> prList = data

   //dbDTO contains PriDTO

    Class DbDTO{
       private PriDTO prdto;
     }

    dbList.stream().filter(x -> (prList.stream().filter(y -> y.getId().equals(x.getRefId()) 
            && y.getName().equals(x.getName()).forEach(x-> x.setPrdto(y)))))
```

Once there is matching found I need to set PriDTO to DbDTO. I am not able to proceed after filtering. Need some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might be looking for `anyMatch` instead of the inner `filter`..

Comment: Yes. If anyMatch then set the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.findFirst` after filtering to get the first one or else null if not matched

```
dbList.forEach(x -> x.setPrdto(prList.stream()
                                     .filter(y -> y.getId().equals(x.getRefId()) 
                                               && y.getName().equals(x.getName()))
                                     .findFirst()
                                     .orElse(null)));
```

Comment: After getting the matched element here set the value using setter `x.setPrdto(..)`

Comment: How can I make a null check on prList? I don't want to add an extra condition if not equal to null before streaming

Comment: `prList` can be null or it's element can be null ?

Comment: prList can be null

Comment: it's better to put all this operation inside an if condition about null check since if prList is null no operation is needed.